# Не стандартная маршрутизация

Tags: linux, сеть, маршрутизация, route

Доброго времени суток!
На своём ПК имею два p2p туннеля *tun0(172.31.255.2),tun1(172.31.255.4)*.
На выходе каждого туннеля имеется своя подсеть вида 192.168.0.0/24.
На выходе каждого туннеля имеется маскарад трафика приходящего из этих туннелей.
При указании маршрута *192.168.0.x via 172.31.255.2* трафик идёт успешно.
Хотел бы иметь возможность обращаться к этим подсетям по адресам:
*172.16.1.x (tun0 -> 192.168.0.x)*
*172.16.2.x (tun1 -> 192.168.0.x)*

Что для этого нужно сделать?
Подойдёт любой вариант, например:
Создать виртуальный интерфейс(слышал о veth, но не разобрался как им пользоваться) и пропустить сначала трафик через него, а далее с подменой адреса обращаться к *tun0*;
Любые махинации с ip/iptables/route;

Буду благодарен за любые наводки по данной теме!
P.S. Доступ имею только своему ПК

ответ @Mike :
`ip route add 0.0.0.0/0 dev tun0 table 101101` 
`ip rule add fwmark 101101 lookup 101101` 
**отправляю пакет**
send: 
`iptables -t mangle -I OUTPUT -d 172.16.1.0/24 -j MARK --set-mark 101101` 
1. s_ip=192.168.0.100 d_ip=172.16.1.22 
`iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT -d 172.16.1.0/24 -j NETMAP --to 192.168.0.0/24` 
2. s_ip=192.168.0.100 d_ip=192.168.0.22 
`iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j SNAT --to 172.31.255.2` 
3. s_ip=172.31.255.2 d_ip=192.168.0.22 
`iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE ##rule is set in out server` 
4. s_ip=192.168.0.1 d_ip=192.168.0.22 

recv: 
1. s_ip=192.168.0.22 d_ip=192.168.0.1 
`@@iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE ##rule is set in out server` 
2. s_ip=192.168.0.22 d_ip=172.31.255.2 
`@@iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j SNAT --to 172.31.255.2` 
3. s_ip=192.168.0.22 d_ip=192.168.0.100 

Верно? Если да, то как быть дальше? Ведь я не смогу изменить s_ip в PREROUTING

Comment: На вскидку в mangle PREROUTING помечаете пакеты для 172.16 подсетей марками. В nat PRE/POST ROUTING преобразуете адреса. С помощью `ip route table N` делаете в разных таблицах маршрутизации маршруты на 192.168 через разные туннели. в `ip rule` задаете правила на основе выставленных марок для заворачивания пакетов в нужную таблицу маршрутизации.

Comment: Ответил в описание, @mike

Comment: У вас пакеты для той подсети рождаются на этой же машине или она маршрутизатор ? Есть одна проблема для локальных пакетов, судя по картинке https://www.opennet.ru/docs/RUS/iptables/misc/iptables-tutorial/images/tables_traverse.jpg  `-t mangle -I OUTPUT` срабатывает _после_ маршрутизации т.е. после `ip rule` и нет ни одной цепочки которая бы работала до маршрутизации для локальных пакетов. Для транзитных же лучше делать на PREROUTING